# Influence the lifecycle execution that a Maven plugin executes (tomcat7:run)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7

I have the compiler and AspectJ Maven plugins at work in the compile phase.

*After* their work I need to execute some *extra* goal ([Hibernate bytecode instrumentation](http://doginpool.blogspot.com/2012/03/bytecode-instrumentation-for-hibernate.html)). It makes sense to tie that to the `process-classes` phase.

I want to run `tomcat7:run`, which [documents](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) the following:

> Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase compile prior to executing itself

If I bind my *extra* goal to `process-classes`, it won't execute, which is not what I want for running Tomcat.

If I bind my *extra* goal to `compile`, its execution order in respect to the compile and AspectJ executions becomes somewhat unreliable (dependent on the order in which the plugins are defined in the POM). It can be done, but it makes me unhappy.

I would rather have `tomcat7:run` execute up to and including `process-classes`. Can this plugin be influenced to do so?

Alternatively I'd be happy to skip the lifecycle execution of the plugin and just hook it into the right lifecycle phase of my own build.

---

For illustration here's some snippets from the output of this build:

```
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:run (default-cli) @ webapp >>>
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ webapp ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ webapp ---
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (aspectj-compile) @ webapp ---
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (hibernate-instrument) @ webapp ---
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:run (default-cli) @ webapp <<<
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:run (default-cli) @ webapp ---
```

The chevrons indicate the plugin's lifecycle invocation.

Comment: I must be missing something -- why can't you just invoke `mvn process-classes tomcat7:run`?

Comment: First of all, it's waste: `tomcat7` is going to re-run the `compile` lifecycle. More importantly: because it does so, compilation is re-done, and the results of my *extra* goal will be overwritten.

Comment: Hm -- for some reason I was under the impression that it was smart enough not to re-invoke clean, compile, etc.

Comment: It would be a neat improvement. Upon inspection I see more plugins re-doing stuff this way, all adding to my build time, for no good reason that I can think of.

Comment: I have created the following Maven JIRA issue on this: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5521

Comment: Feel free to vote for the above Maven JIRA issue :)

Comment: Updated URL: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5521